# Trouble signing out

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry

We have some SpringBoot (with Spring Security 5 OAuth2) applications hosted on Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF).  We use the SSO tile in PCF, which is integrated with ADFS that enables us to get credentials stored in AD.  This implementation creates multiple cookies and saml tokens.  Spring session invalidation does not clear out all these cookies.

Is there a suggested mechanism to clear out these cookies in LogoutSuccessHandler?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Spring Boot which cookies to delete in the security configuration:

```
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("https://fooo.com")
            .deleteCookies("SESSION", "x_token", "x_user")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll();
```